# Redhat and Centos servers glibc errors

Tags: centos, rhel, glibc

Please forgive if I am not wording this correctly and my current lack of information, but I am losing my mind trying to figure this out and I am not currently behind the servers in question. I have two servers, one is Redhat 4 and one is Centos 4. Both of them get the following error with every binary it seems that requires glibc to function

```
/usr/sbin/sshd /lib/tls/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.4' not found (required by /usr/lib/libz.so.1) /usr/sbin/sshd: /lib/tls/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.3.4' not found (required by /usr/lib/libz.so.6)
```

replace sshd with yum and other programs that all have the same issue essentially. These are not my servers and according to the owner nothing was actively done to them. One failed about 6 months ago with this error and one as recently as a month ago.

Has anybody seen anything like this before or have any clues as to what I can do to correct it? Can't use yum since it doesn't work due to this. I will be able to gather more information if requested in a few days but I'm just trying to get an idea as to what is happening since Google is failing me on this one.

Comment: You can run `rpm -Va` which checks for corruption in the files that were installed from an RPM file. I'm skeptical that nothing at all changed since it's weird that they're all now asking for different versions of glibc.

Comment: RedHat 4 EOL happened 4 years ago. I'm not surprised the servers are taking the their toll.  In essence i'm just repeating what Bratchley said: if any package (through `rpm` or `yum`) was meddled with in the last 4 years, they may be using binaries out of sync with the libc.  Nothing/noone currently is looking after the dependency tree of RHEL 4.

Comment: Yeah I was under the same impression and mentioned this to the guy, but he has been adamant about sticking to this version for now since it is hosting legacy applications. I was hoping to find a way to start least return it to its original, albeit out of date and asking for trouble state. Can the binaries/library structure be rebuilt from CD safely? I apologize I just haven't dealt with anything like this in years of dealing with Linux. Spoiled by up to date boxes and backed up VMs ^^

Comment: Is this on RHEL/CentOS **4.8**?

Comment: No idea at the moment, any idea on what I can try if it is? Thank you in advance

Comment: It is obvious something/someone upgraded/copied a library for someplace else. Short of going to the original repos and getting the offending rpm/files, I would put together test machines with the application(s) and try a migration.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect someone's mixed some RHEL5 into the RHEL4, and in some cases the versioning is very intolerant of dumb repo tricks -- as in, we all agree there are things you shouldn't do, and this message is especially common with one of those things.

so, rpm -qif usr/sbin/sshd and see what it was built for.  I'm going to bet it wasn't built for RHEL4.  If so, steel yourself and downgrade to the latest version within your distro, and prepare to backport a newer release if you so choose.

I still have one RHEL4 box also.  We need to balance what we know we should do, with mitigating the things we cannot yet change.  As we get a little grey, so does the line.